# Lambda Function showing Error getting object from bucket then timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm not a coding person, so I will try to describe the best as possible I can my issue.

I have a Web environment running on Elastic Beanstalk, that environment has a lambda function.
What the function does is: Access an S3 bucket, get a zip file and import the content to the database.

I have a replica of the same environment running OK for another company.

I checked the Security groups, VPC and respective related functions, and they look ok.

Is anyone able to give me a light? I have found different solutions on this website and none of them helped me.

I'm not sure if my lambda function can access the S3 then is timing out or if is timing out before accessing S3.

Here is the CloudWatch log:

```
START RequestId: db4211ca-58e9-47d5-859a-93183cc1fbff Version: $LATEST

FunctionHandler for bohforecasting, ACL_175_BHDW18.zip

Fetching TaskId for ACL_175_BHDW18.zip.

TaskId for ACL_175_BHDW18.zip is 273.

Source for ACL_175_BHDW18.zip is ACL.

Error getting object ACL_175_BHDW18.zip from bucket bohforecasting.

The operation was canceled.

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at MAGS3SSIMLoader.Function.FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context) in 

C:\Users\mjhol\projects\source\Forecasting-MAG\workers\SSIMUnZipperAWSLambda\MAGS3SSIMLoader\Function.cs:line 70
END RequestId: db4211ca-58e9-47d5-859a-93183cc1fbff
REPORT RequestId: db4211ca-58e9-47d5-859a-93183cc1fbff  Duration: 534775.73 ms  Billed Duration: 534776 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 86 MB  Init Duration: 295.18 ms
```

Comment: It seems ACL_175_BHDW18.zip is the issue. If zip file is in S3, did you set the permission so that Lambda can access S3?

Comment: Yes,
It is using an S3 SG with full permission.
Not sure if helps, but on the web browser console it is showing an error message saying " Get https://mywebsite.com 502 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 502 -  creator error.js:17

Comment: You mean policy, not SG (security group) maybe? 502 error is often shown when Lambda syntax like json is wrong. And I think duration time is 534 sec, this is rather long.